# JWT Auth, Way to access AccessToken when you logged in

Tags: authentication, jwt, token

i'm having a diffculty with Access Token.
And i'm new in web dev, taking a role in front-end.

So far, my web site is connected with server for log in API, and i can verify user infomation after logged in at console.

However, i'm wondering the way to get access to Access Token which is issued from the server.
So, the logic is as follows,

- When i sucess logged in with correct user information, AccessToken and Refresh Tokens are issued.
- I needed a code to access to Access Token, so if i have, i can access to prevented pages (such as, MyPage)
- The Access Token has 30min of expires, so after logged in 30min,the issued Access Token must be expired and lost its access rigth to private pages.

Summary !

- I'm wondering the way to code the AccessToken in Client side to server side after logged in. Found some of informations that saying include Access Token in headers request in Client side.
- How can i code whether the Access Token is expired after 30 min and reqesting again to issue the access-token when i access to private pages with access-token expired state.
- Then, if server can find there is a refresh-token in Client side, then issues access token very easily.
- Wondering should i put all of the pages that check wether AccessToken is alive?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it handle by token middle-ware between front-end to IdP(ID provider) server.
It automatically refresh the access token by refresh-token.

[image: List item]

The middle-ware's roles

- refresh token together with the access token when the user login is processed.
- access token and refresh token are re-issued when the refresh is executed
- saved the access token and refresh token into local storage (usually called cookies)
- If an access token is expired when you execute an API, it will be able to execute the API with a new access token if a refresh token is valid
- If an refresh token is expired when you execute an API, it will be able to execute the API with a new access token if a refresh token is expired after got new refresh token.

Popular IdP is [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) provides middle-ware for multiple languages.
Java, [Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/), [Spring Boot](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/), [Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular), [React](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak)

sorry, I missed your question

1. I'm wondering the way to code the AccessToken in Client side to server side after logged in. Found some of informations that saying include Access Token in headers request in Client side.

**The front-end access an access token and decode it for getting user's information, role and expires time**

2. How can i code whether the Access Token is expired after 30 min and reqesting again to issue the access-token when i access to private pages with access-token expired state.

**middle-ware takes care the life time of access token**

3. Then, if server can find there is a refresh-token in Client side, then issues access token very easily.

**Yes,**

4. Wondering should i put all of the pages that check wether AccessToken is alive?

**It stored in local storage in single place and use it from mutiple pages**

Comment: Hello, Bench Vue
I liked your answer, and truly thanks for the sincere answering. Appreciate!
By the way, Unfortunatlly, i can't use localStorage method, but cookie. They are already in cookies, and i must use them as using cookies..!
Thanks again, and i haven't knew there are middle-ware method for this auth. Thanks ! and have a great weekend

Comment: @Nam, Thanks to hear my sharing help to you.  OK, good luck to handle with cookies.

Comment: Thanks again, can i ask you one more thing?
I'm keep trying to access the cookie(there are already access and refresh token in it) from well structured api after i logged in.
However, even i used some of packages to read cookie, such as js-cookie, and i wrote "console.log(Cookies.get("access_token"))"  after well logged in with status code 200.

However, the console still print undefined or just blank. So, currently, the login function works well, bringing cookie also well, i can find them in Dev console in Applicatoin. However, i don't know how to access to those. Could you gimme a hand?

Comment: Nope, sorry dude. Over the testing, we've found that we can access to the access token in cookie as turning off the 'httpOnly' attribute, so now finally client can access to the cookie. Now, however, our dilemma is "Will this be safe from XSS attack? and i think not, then, will there be any safe way to using cookie over this auth?"

Comment: I don't know about XSS, how to hack by client side to attack to server. But I have some experience to handle cookies, can you makes separate question for your cookie problem with detail information and source code? I can try it to get an access-token from cookies.

Comment: There important points I don't agree with in this answer, see my updated answer for details

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I might not agree with in @BenchVue answer:

- Client should retrieve user data from ID-tokens only. Access-tokens `audience` are resource-server(s), can be opaque and should be used only as authorisation headers.
- Authorization-server (middle-ware in the answer) **defines** tokens expiries. It does not refresh it auto-magically. Clients must handle tokens refreshing, which can be done pro-actively as OAuth2 token responses contain expiry in adition to the token itself (even for opaque token).

Do not code a gripped weel. [Pick a lib](https://openid.net/developers/certified/). You're very very likely to  make security breaches otherwize. Plus you'll waste a lot of time implementing stuff like:

- redirection to authorization-server for login / logout when user tries to access a protected route
- silent access-token refreshing (just before it expires) using refresh-token
- JWT adding as Bearer `Authorization` header to secured resource-server
- etc.